# Mysql search data from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 tables named

```
jobs
property
matrimonial
services
vehicle
```

All tables have field "City"

I want to search data city wise from those table. I mean query will return 10 rows in one time and rows will be from those 5 tables

Let me expalin

jobs = id, jobid, username, minexp, location, city

metrimonial = id, gender,  dob, color, city

property = id, persqft, type, area, location, city

I need full columns using city='London'

Could you please help me

Comment: It's easy by using `join`,,show your tables structure and relationship among them or you may use `union all` as well

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, it is not clear what u want to do?

Comment: **Bhupendra** But i have different fields in those table. Only city field is same

Comment: plz edit your question and explain all your data structure of those five tables, otherwise it will be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the data, and know from which table it's coming, you may do

```
SELECT 'jobCity' as source, City
FROM jobs 
WHERE City = 'London'
UNION 
SELECT 'propertyCity' as source, City
FROM property
WHERE City = 'London'
UNION 
SELECT 'matrimonialCity' as source, City
FROM matrimonial
WHERE City = 'London
--etc.
```

Comment: But i need full table columns from those tables. I don't need particular field

Comment: but while using `union` keep in mind one thing that all `select` query must have same number of `columns`.

Comment: Let me expalin
jobs = id, jobid, username, minexp, location, city
metrimonial = id, gender,  dob, color, city
property = id, persqft, type, area, location, city

I need full columns using city='London'

Comment: same no of columns alongwith type

Comment: @bhupendra well, this is doable, but won't make sense. Each part of an union must have the same number of column, and each column (in order) must have the same type. So you'll have to duplicate all "uncommon" columns" from your 5 tables in each union, which will make an awful (and rather unusable) query.

Answer (score 0):

ill sugest you to better make VIEW taking all these tables and then fetc

Comment: **Bhupendra** view will take more space in db

Comment: @user2180069 Can you please elaborate how would you achieve this using views? It is not possible